# How to make Navigation links responsive to browser resize

Tags: css, layout, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make a [website](http://goo.gl/hxYfU) I am developing responsive, so far the elements that I want to make responsive to change in the the browser window are working well, except for the navigation text size and position...

The **HTML** make up for the web page  looks like this

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="bio.php">Bio</a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="resume.php">Resume</a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="reel.php">Reel</a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="recommendation.php">Recommendation</a></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></div> 
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="navtext"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></div> 
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The media query I have added to the CSS looks like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
   #nav{
      width: 905px;
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 500px;
   }

   #nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 10px 0px 0px 1px;
     margin: 0;
   }

   #nav ul li {
     list-style: none;
     float: left;
     padding: 0 0 0 20px;
     font-weight: normal;
  }

  .navtext a {
     font-size:2.2em;
     padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px; 
  }
}
```

After screen resize - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvaKe.png

Comment: When you get down to smaller screen sizes, user percentages. Also, remove the only screen. This will add mobile support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by making the width and the margin-left of the #nav div less

```
#nav{
  width: 905px; /* too wide for (max-width: 479px) screen */
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 500px; /* too wide for (max-width: 479px) screen */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For responsive navigation i use this http://tinynav.viljamis.com/ (its moderm looking  responsive solution for small screens) and of cause you should use only em and % for your elements.